How to express dashes in coordinates
I want to set the dashes of my Line2D as coordinates instead of points. How can I do this?
I wanted to try for example setting the dashes as 1/3 the length of my segment. I tried something like this but the result is not correct:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=300, layout="constrained")

point_1 = (0, 0)
point_2 = (1, 1)

data_coords = ax.transData.transform(point_2) - ax.transData.transform(point_1)
length = np.linalg.norm(data_coords)
value = 1/3 * length * 72 / fig.dpi
ax.plot((point_1[0], point_2[0]), (point_1[1], point_2[1]), dashes=[value, value])


I would expect here a dash a stop and a dash all of equal lengths! What am I doing wrong?

Where do you get the value of 72 from?

It's the conversion from inches to points (used in the dashes)

Divide value by the diagonal length in the axes coords, i.e., np.sqrt(2) in this case, e.g.,
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=300, layout="constrained")

point_1 = (0, 0)
point_2 = (1, 1)

data_coords = ax.transData.transform(point_2) - ax.transData.transform(point_1)
length = np.linalg.norm(data_coords)
value = (1/3 * length * 72 / fig.dpi) / np.sqrt(2)
ax.plot((point_1[0], point_2[0]), (point_1[1], point_2[1]), dashes=[value, value])

and you'll get what you expect.
Or, more generically:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=300, layout="constrained")

point_1 = (0, 0)
point_2 = (1, 1)

data_coords = ax.transData.transform(point_2) - ax.transData.transform(point_1)
length = np.linalg.norm(data_coords) / np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(point_2) - np.asarray(point_1))
value = 1/3 * length * 72 / fig.dpi
ax.plot((point_1[0], point_2[0]), (point_1[1], point_2[1]), dashes=[value, value])


Although this seems to work for 1/3 I still have problems if I try to segment it for more parts, for example if you try with 1/5 and layout="tight" I get this result: https://imgur.com/a/W9uWec3
Which is visibly off

maybe there is something about the tight layout that screws things up!
